# Get youtube channel's videos data (isrc)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How can I get full information from videos on a youtube channel (ISRC, Video_ISRC, Asset_ID, UPC) using YouTube or other APIs.

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string channelname = txtChannel.Text;
    string developerKey = "AI39si4f9ZH80eTwUdmc3sd89kYTxEjWxWEXIPyW2hP8LIYEDJjoUrcl26jEbpzYJpaH3Bckk-4GVtfgEPQ9GkrDERRydwaobQ";
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\youtubechannelcontent.txt");
    YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(channelname, developerKey);
    YouTubeRequest _request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
    string _feedUrl = String.Format("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{0}/uploads", channelname);
    Feed<Video> _vediofeed = _request.Get<Video>(new Uri(_feedUrl));
    int max = _vediofeed.TotalResults;
    int index = 1;
    MessageBox.Show(max.ToString());
    YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
    while (index<max)
    {
        string feedUrl = String.Format("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{0}/uploads?max-results=50&start-index={1}", channelname, index);
        Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(new Uri(feedUrl));
        foreach (var item in videoFeed.Entries)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(item.Author + "," + item.CommmentCount   +  "," + item.ETag + "," + item.Id + "," +item.RatingAverage+   "," +item.Title+ "," +item.Updated+ "," +item.Uploader+ "," +item.VideoId+ "," +item.ViewCount+ "," +item.WatchPage);  
            //sw.WriteLine(item.Title+","+item.YouTubeEntry);
        }
        index += 50;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't get ISRC, Video_ISRC, Asset_ID, and UPC of videos.

Comment: I dont know what are information ypu need to this is my issue when I use API to get vedio information i didnt find this fields (ISRC,UPC,...) so i'm asking if there any way to get this informations

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand?

Comment: I need to know how to get isrc of youtube video using API

Comment: what is ISRC, can you link to some docs

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity you can use the api v2 like this:

```
const string channelName = "YourChannel";
var URL =string.Format("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{0}/uploads",
                                                                    channelName);
using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(URL))
{
    while (reader.Read()) 
    {
        if (reader.Name.Equals("media:player"))
        {
                string attribute = reader["url"];
                if (attribute != null)
                {
                    Response.Write("Youtube Video Link" + attribute + "<br />");
                }                            
        }
    }
}
```

You can achieve similarly using `v3` but It will require some more work